# iphone Social framework, make text read only

Tags: iphone, social-networking, slcomposeviewcontroller

Here is my code:

```
SLComposeViewController*fvc = [SLComposeViewController
                                       composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [fvc setInitialText:string];
        [fvc addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"email.png"]];
        [fvc setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
```

How to make facebook post title and text read only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that can be done with the standard framework. (The idea being that posting to Facebook is left as a user activity, not something you can force on them.)

You *could*, of course, go lower-level and talk to the Facebook API directly but that would be a lot more work. You'll probably find that people don't change the suggested text very much anyway.